# How to use composite index in range query in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-index

I have a table "test" with two field, field1 and field2, and an composite index created field1_field2(field1, field2).
here is a sql : select * from test force index(field1_field2) where field1 > 100 and field2 = 2 limit 200

and it doesnt run very well.
I Explained it and found that only field1 condition used by index query, field2 condition was ignored....

I want know why, and I need a perfectly answer

there are lots of data with field1 > 100 and lots of data with field2 = 2

Comment: Try swapping your index columns to `(field2, field1)`.

Comment: Also, read up [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part).

Answer (score 4):

For *that* query, you need `INDEX(field2, field1)`, in *that* order.  Put the `=` columns first in an index.  Once you hit a "range" (such as `>`), that's the last part of the index that will be used.

Here's an [*Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .